# Issue bootstrapping Aurelia

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm trying to convert a project using gulp w/ JSPM to webpack. I've been basing all of the config on the [Aurelia skeleton project on Github](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack/).

This is the error I get:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String] at createLoader 
(http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:12324:18)
at http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:12379:12
From previous event:
at run (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:12375:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:12402:1)
at Object.136 (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:12403:30)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:50:30)
at Object.210 (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:29505:18)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:50:30)
at 0.module.exports.ctor.super_ (http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:148:18)
at http://localhost:8080/app.e166274c9bde327af4ef.bundle.js:151:10

Unhandled rejection No PLATFORM.Loader is defined and there is neither a System API (ES6) or a Require API (AMD) globally available to load your app.
```

webpack.config.js: https://pastebin.com/XQ7ZeBTJ

main.js: https://pastebin.com/Tzs24JYj

pacakge.json: https://pastebin.com/yE7tPwML

index.ejs: https://pastebin.com/GdXcEAJz

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share your `package.json` file as well as your `index.html` or `index.ejs` file? It's a little hard to discern what the issue is with what you have provided.

Comment: Hey @DwayneCharrington I added those files for you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @m0ngr31 can you please try something for me. What happens if you update `html-webpack-plugin` to its latest released version?

Comment: From what it looks like I am already on the newest version. @DwayneCharrington